# Getting an error when using "require" in ruby

Tags: ruby

I just started Ruby. This is what I tried:

```
   require'F:\RubymineProjects\practice122013\Coordinatev2'

   class XYZCoordinate < Coordinate


     attr_accessor :z
     @@newtotal=0

     def initialize(x,y,z)
       super(x,y)
       @z=z
       @@newtotal+=1

     end

     def to_s
       return "(#@x, #@y, #@z)"

     end

     def XYZCoordinate.total
       return "Number of 3D-coordinates are: #@@newtotal"

     end

  end

p1=XYZCoordinate.new(0,0,0)

puts p1.to_s

p2=XYZCoordinate.new(1,5,5)

puts p2.to_s

puts XYZCoordinate.total


and this is the error I get:


C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) F:/RubymineProjects/practice122013/XYZCoordinate.rb
F:/RubymineProjects/practice122013/XYZCoordinate.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Coordinate (NameError)

(0, 0)

    from -e:1:in `load'

2

    from -e:1:in `<main>'

3
```

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use windows backslash paths in ruby requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to correct the problem.

```
 require"F:\\RubymineProjects\\practice122013\\Coordinatev2"
 require"F:\\RubymineProjects\\practice122013\\Coordinate"
```

I had to specify where those 2 files were.

Comment: I guess people did not find my question intelligent, however not everyone is an expert programmer. I am sure some of you remember when you started.

Comment: Well congratulations.

Comment: make your question answered

Comment: Thank you, one more day before I can make it answered.